# AngularJS tabs with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099538/angularjs-tabs-acting-weird) and was wondering maybe somebody has had a similar problem and maybe know how to deal with it? My [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/opxB2Jfi0Xf0Tq1780vz?p=preview)!

Angular tabs are not working with ng-repeat. It seems that Angular can't put together tab value from click and tab value from ng-show.
My code:

```
<section ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul ng-init="tab=1">
        <li ng-repeat="item in data">
          <a href ng-click="tab = item.thingy">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-show="tab === item.thingy">
        <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" width="50px"><br>
        {{item.year}}</div>
</div>
</section>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    name: "First",
    title: "oneTitle",
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    year: "2013",
    img: "http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wp_400/1/5/42735.jpg",
    thingy: 1
  }, {
    name: "third",
    title: "twoTitle",
    description: "Quisque pulvinar libero sed eros ornare",
    year: "2014",
    img: "http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wp_400/1/1/8519.jpg",
    thingy: 2
  }, {
    name: "Second",
    title: "threeTitle",
    description: "Cras accumsan massa vitae tortor vehicula .",
    year: "2015",
    img: "http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wp_400/1/5/43326.jpg",
    thingy: 3
  }, {
    name: "fourth",
    title: "FourTitle",
    description: "Suspendisse vitae mattis magna.",
    year: "2011",
    img: "http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wp_400/1/5/42413.jpg",
    thingy: 4
   }];
}]);
```

Comment: I don't really know the answer to this but what I can do is recommend using [UI-Bootstrap's tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) which work perfectly fine using this type of behaviour

Comment: Thanks! Will try. But I can't stand not knowing the reason for this setup not working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this (one is dcodesmith's great answer).

### Use [`Controller As`](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax

If you wish to define **view-only variables** on your view (*as you did in your example*),
**use the [`Controller As`](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax**.

One of the pros you'll get using this approach is direct access to define and modify variables **on the controller's scope**. while in your case, the `tab` variable has been modified on the child scopes of `ng-repeat` / `ng-init`

---

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

    <ul ng-init="vm.tab=1">
        <li ng-repeat="item in vm.data">
          <a href ng-click="vm.tab = item.thingy">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.data" ng-show="vm.tab === item.thingy">
        <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" width="50px"><br>
        {{item.year}}</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.data = [{
       name: "First",
       title: "oneTitle",
       description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
       year: "2013",
       img: "http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wp_400/1/5/42735.jpg",
       thingy: 1
     },
     //...
    ];

  }
]);
```

## http://plnkr.co/edit/1q0AVrcqhIZRjFvVSVIP?p=preview

[image]

Comment: We dont need following line <div ng-repeat="item in vm.data" ng-show="vm.tab === item.thingy">

Comment: @VirendraShenviVelingkar this provided in the OP example. what you are suggesting is to keep the object itself instead of the index. i agree this is better however, i stay loyal to the OP example :)

Comment: :) Yeah you are right, I thought making the code more clean. :p Lets be loyal to the OP example.

Comment: I love you guys! Seriously!

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I think you should declare/initialise your `$scope.tab` in the controller, as well as the function to set the selected tab. Best practise IMO.

NOTE: Adopting this way of doing also helps testing easier.

**HTML**

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data">
          <a href="#" ng-click="setTab(item.thingy)">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.tab = 1;

// for the debugging reason. 
$scope.$watch('tab', function (newTab, oldTab) {
    console.log(newTab, oldTab);
});

$scope.setTab = function (pos) {
  $scope.tab = pos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

modifications in script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        name: "First",
        title: "oneTitle",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        year: "2013",
        img: "http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wp_400/1/5/42735.jpg",
        thingy: 1
    }, {
        name: "third",
        title: "twoTitle",
        description: "Quisque pulvinar libero sed eros ornare",
        year: "2014",
        img: "http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wp_400/1/1/8519.jpg",
        thingy: 2
    }, {
        name: "Second",
        title: "threeTitle",
        description: "Cras accumsan massa vitae tortor vehicula .",
        year: "2015",
        img: "http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wp_400/1/5/43326.jpg",
        thingy: 3
    }, {
        name: "fourth",
        title: "FourTitle",
        description: "Suspendisse vitae mattis magna.",
        year: "2011",
        img: "http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wp_400/1/5/42413.jpg",
        thingy: 4
    }];

  $scope.details = $scope.data[0];

  $scope.GetDetails = function(obj)
  {
    $scope.details = obj;
  }

}]
);
```

In HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <ul ng-init="tab=1">
            <li ng-repeat="item in data">
              <a href ng-click="GetDetails(item);">{{item.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          {{details.thingy}} <br/>
          {{details.name}}<br/>
          {{details.title}}<br/>
          {{details.description}}<br/>
          {{details.year}}<br/>
          <img ng-src="{{details.img}}" width="50px"><br>
        </div>
</div>
```