# How to implement dynamic ons-tab with ons-lazy repeat

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui2

Onsen UI: v2.0.1

AngularJS: 1.5.9

I am building an Android and IOS application that requires dynamic tabs (ons-tab) like in native applications. The content in each tabs can be up to a hundred items. So I want to use ons-lazy-repeat for the ons-tab content to minimize memory consumptions. How do I go about achieving this (dynamic tabs and ons-lazy-repeat ) with Onsen UI. I have searched online and I couldn’t see any solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `ons-lazy-repeat` component is [described in detail in the documentation](https://onsen.io/v1/reference/ons-lazy-repeat.html).

Dynamic tabs can easily be achieved by using the [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) clause of AngularJS. If you don't want to load the content of each tab right at the beginning, you have multiple options like [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) or [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to make sure that only the content of the current visible tab is loaded. You may access and check the visibility of the `$index` variable that is available in the `ng-repeat`s scope to do so.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254973/angularjs-tabs-with-ng-repeat) how this may be done. Onsen offers a tabbar and tab components which will work the same way as the tab div's in the questions answer.